# Winston Logger return exact logged string

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I'm using Winston to do logging for my node application. I'm trying to achieve grabbing exactly value Winston logged into the log file. Example in this scenario it will return :-

`{"message":"New S3!","level":"info"}`

I've tested to console log the function and check certain package function in the winston, so far couldn't find any way to return it.

```js
var logger = winston.createLogger({
 transports: [
  transport, //This is to upload to 
  new winston.transports.File(options.file), //Will log into file
  new winston.transports.Console(options.console) //Will log at console display
 ]
});

var loggedVal = logger.info('New S3!');
console.log(loggedVal);
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? I don't understand really.
Maybe you can set the `format: winston.format.json()` property in the `createLogger` options object

Comment: Basically i hope i can get exactly value written in log by winston. If winston logged `{"message":"New S3!","level":"info"}`, i hope can store that into `var loggedVal` variable

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for testing output of console transport. So the solution is valid for jest env only.

We can use  jest-mock-process package as described [there](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-process)
Or create simple spies

```
const mockStdoutWrite = jest.spyOn(process.stdout, 'write').mockImplementation(function () { return true; });
const mockStdout = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(function () { });

logger.debug('Debug message');
expect(mockStdoutWrite).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, ....);
```

Answer (score -1):

Winston logger wasn't designed to do what you're trying to achieve, and there are hardly any use cases for what you're trying to do so I doubt winston would have that feature.